# I made my viewport background black and dont know how to change it back

Tags: 3d-view

[image]

While I was working accidentally got distracted and pressed some keys not sure which ones... I only saw a menu pop up for a second and then suddenly my viewport background became black.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not sure what you did, but a good place to check is in the World Properties Tab. The settings I have highlighted are the defaults - make sure yours match.

[image: Background]

Comment: Thanks your photo helped a lot! I managed to fix it. The problem was the viewport shading options which was set to the last one "rendered" apparently that makes the background black.

Comment: No problem. The "rendered" background should be whatever you have set to your World Background (not viewport) - the top of the two grey boxes that are in the section I highlighted (between surface and strength).